# Two identities for integration to arcsin

Tags: integration

There are two identities for the following integration (leads to $arcsin$):
$$
\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{3-x^{2}}}
$$

The **1st**:
$$
\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^{2}}} = arcsin(\frac{x}{a}) + C
$$

The **2nd**:
$$
\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} = arcsin(x) + C
$$

It can be easily seen that the **1st** method generalizes for additional scenarios - **supposedly**, because that I don't know what to do when instead of $x^2$ I'll get a complicated function.

The **2nd** method is simpler and I sense that there's a better & generic way to use this integral identity.
For instance, how do you find the integral with the **2nd** identity? As follows:
$$
\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{3-x^{2}}} = \int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{3\cdot(1-\frac{x^{2}}{3})}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^{2}}{3}}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot arcsin(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}) + C
$$
But this way, I found the integral using my intuition, because that the 2nd identity is true only for $x^2$.

My question is how to integrate a similar but more complicated functions?
What is the "correct way" to integrate **without intuition** using the **2nd** identity?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @MarkLao: I've edit my message. My question is: What is the "correct way" to integrate **without intuition**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the change of variable $x=a y$; so $dx= a \space dy$. So,$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^{2}}} =\int\frac{ a \space dy}{\sqrt{a^2 -a^2y^2}}=\int\frac{ dy}{\sqrt{1 -y^2}}=\sin^{-1}(y)=\sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{ a})$$

Answer (score 0):

To use the first identity in your example, let $a=\sqrt3$.

Comment: I meant using the 2nd identity sorry :)